# Trouble setting up apache on vmware

Tags: php, apache, vmware

I'm trying to set up a virtual machine (vmware workstation 8.0.2) running CentOS 6.2 (i386) to mirror my live server so I can work locally. I'm running Windows 7 64bit. I have installed CentOS, PHP & MySQL they all seem to be running fine.

I now need to get it to access my files on the windows machine. I've installed the VMware tools and can now see the shared folder in /mnt/hgfs/Work/. I now need to point apache to the files here so it can use them, to do this I edited httpd.conf from:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

to

```
DocumentRoot "/mnt/hgfs" (also tried DocumentRoot "/mnt/hgfs/Work")
```

when I restart apache it fails and I get:

```
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 293 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
DocumentRoot must be a directory
```

I've used Linux, but not very often so it's probably something obvious I've missed, I'd really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: This looks like a permission problem: Please post the output of `ls -lah /mnt/hgfs/Work` and the user/group of your apache user

Comment: the output is:
    drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  32K Feb  6 19:56 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 1 root root 4.1K Feb  7 23:15 ..
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  12K Jan 23 15:14 Accelerator
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  12K Apr  8  2011 Acolyte
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4.0K Aug 29  2010 Alex
...

Comment: OK, looks like file-level permissions are OK. MAC-level permissions? Do you have AppArmor or SELinux running? Oups - see answer by @PFY below.

Comment: SE Linux file-labeling just doesn't work on NTFS partitions; the HGFS isn't the actual problem - but when the underlying FS of the host OS can't label, this can't function...just wonder, why one can't just pass default file-labels for vmhgfs mount-points (as one can do with owner/group/permissions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you are not having trouble with SELinux, which is enforcing by default on CentOS 6.
You can either disable it by editing /etc/selinux/config or read up on it here
http://rackerhacker.com/2012/01/25/getting-started-with-selinux/

Comment: I've disabled SELinux now, and I can restart Apache successfully. However now when i go to local host I'm asked for a username and password (like I would be if there was an .htaccess password). There's no .htaccess, just a file called index.php - any ideas?

Comment: Actually it seems to be down to the contents of the folder, another one works fine - thanks for the answer!